# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Server doesn't connect to WiFi using `netplan`

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, internet, netplan

I have a laptop (no Ethernet, WiFi only) with freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 [x64]. Trying to use `netplan` to connect to the home WiFi, but it doesn't connect.

What I'm doing:

1. With `ip addr` aquired the name of WiFi interface adapter : `wlo1`
2. Created the config file in `/etc/netplan/01-my-network.yaml` with the following content:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlo1:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "NETWORK_NAME": 
          password: "MY_PASSWORD"
```

3. After this: `sudo netplan generate`
4. `sudo netplan apply`

However, I can't connect to anything (even after the reboot). `ip addr` does show that I don't have any IP addresses assigned to `wlo1`.

Running `ping -c 10 www.google.com` results into `ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`.

How to fix this?

P.S. Also tried:

- without line `renderer: networkd`. Same result.
- remove the file `\etc\netplan\00-installer-config.yaml` which was created automatically during installation. Same result.

Answer (score 4):

Needed to install `wpa_supplicant`, which is not included in `Ubuntu Server 20.04.1` by default:

`sudo apt install -y wpasupplicant`

After installation and reboot, it works.

Comment: To be clear... ubuntu server does not have wifi support out of the box, it must be connected to ethernet before wifi will work :/